# flutter ClientException in http requests

Tags: flutter

This is the function containing the request :

```
Future<String> getRequest(String serviceName, Map<String, String> a) async {
  var responseBody = '{"data": "", "status": "NOK"}';
  try {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(_urlBase + '$_serverApi$serviceName', headings: a);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      responseBody = response.body;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // An error was received
    throw new Exception("GET ERROR");
  }
  return responseBody;
}
```

and this is where i call it :

```
void _confirm() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.saveAndValidate()) {
      print(_formKey.currentState.value);
      Map<String, String> c =
          Map<String, String>.from(_formKey.currentState.value);
      // just below
      var a = await auth.getRequest('se_connecter', c);

      print(a);
    } else {
      print(_formKey.currentState.value);
      print("validation failed");
    }
}
```

everytime i try it, the code in the try bloc fails, and it throws the exception (ClientException after i removed try and catch bloc)

This the exception stacktrace :

```
I/flutter (10979): #0      IOClient.send 
package:http/src/io_client.dart:65
I/flutter (10979): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (10979): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed 
package:http/src/base_client.dart:176
I/flutter (10979): #2      BaseClient.get 
package:http/src/base_client.dart:35
I/flutter (10979): #3      get.<anonymous closure> 
package:http/http.dart:46
I/flutter (10979): #4      _withClient 
package:http/http.dart:166
I/flutter (10979): #5      get 
package:http/http.dart:46
I/flutter (10979): #6      getRequest 
package:event_app/auth.dart:125
I/flutter (10979): #7      ConnectPageState._confirm 
package:event_app/pages/connect_page.dart:28
I/flutter (10979): #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:706
I/flutter (10979): #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:789
I/flutter (10979): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
I/flutter (10979): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:486
I/flutter (10979): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:264
I/flutter (10979): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.
```

Comment: Can you add stacktrace of the exception to question?

Comment: The problem is related to allowLegacyUnsafeRenegotiation [It has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75262997/14208424)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was the ssl encryption, so i removed it from my backend.

Comment: what did you remove?

Comment: in the flask app, in  app.run() function i added ssl_context='adhoc' , so that it runs on HTTPS with an SSL encryption instead of just HTTP

Answer (score 2):

In my case (sometimes instead of blank appeared the error "HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received") the call was to an https address using Microsoft Internet Information Services as backend, in the SSL settings of the website in IIS i had mistakenly set "Client certificates: Accept" instead of "Client certificates: Ignore", setting "Ignore" solved the problem.